# Ranking within groups in R, how many unique variables per group?

Tags: r

Very beginner R person here.

I would like to count the number of A-s across the data, but want to count only one per person. How to do this in R?

My data looks like this:

```
Group1    Group2
Jack        A        
Joe         B
Anne        C
Jack        A
Joe         A
Anne        B
Jack        B
Joe         C
```

I managed to arrange the data by person names, but have no idea how to count the As but only one per person

So the desired number of As is 2 in this data. My real data is much larger with several hundreds of As, that need to be reduced.

Appreciate any answer, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 summarise(count = n_distinct(Group1[Group2 == "A"]))

  count
1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution is:

```
colSums(table(MyData$Group1, MyData$Group2) > 0)
A B C 
2 3 2
```